# how to convert json string to map dynamically

Tags: java, json

I have a json ouput like this  -

```
  {"menu": {
   "id": "12",
   "value": "File",
   "popup": {
       "menuitem": [
                  {"op1": "New", "op11": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                  {"op2": "Open", "op21": "OpenDoc()"},
                  {"op3": "Close", "op31": "CloseDoc()"}
                   ]
            }
      }}
```

I want whatever is the key and order, it should return the key-value pair in a map like this and I do not want to harcode any key-

```
      id=12
      value=File
      op1=New
      op11=CreateNewDoc()
      op2=Open
      op21=OpenDoc()
      op3=Close
      op31=CloseDoc()
```

how will I do it?

Comment: Have you used Jackson or Gson?

Comment: Use a JSON serialization framework and build a custom de-serializer.

Comment: @aksappy, yes I did but I could not find any a way of doing this without harcoding key/value

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at using `javax.json.stream.JsonParser` (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the standard [Java JSON Stream APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/package-summary.html), this will produce the [java.util.Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you want:

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
String keyName = null;

JsonParser jsonParser = Json.createParser(new StringReader(json));

while (jsonParser.hasNext())
{
  JsonParser.Event event = jsonParser.next();

  if (JsonParser.Event.KEY_NAME.equals(event))
  {
    keyName = jsonParser.getString();
  }
  else if (JsonParser.Event.VALUE_STRING.equals(event))
  {
    values.put(keyName, jsonParser.getString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jackson Json.

first. I changed Json string to JsonNode.

ex) JsonString to JsonNode

```
public static JsonNode jsonStringToJsonNode(String json){
    ObjectMapper mp = new ObjectMapper();   

    try {
        return mp.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage.
ex)

```
JsonNode json = jsonStringToJsonNode(jsonstring)
json.get("menu").get("id")  => result 12
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: will it give the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert JSON string into `Map<String,Object>` then extract the desired values using **Recursion**.

Recursion method:

```
public static void process(String key, Object value, Map<String, String> newMap){
    if (value instanceof String) {
        newMap.put(key, (String) value);
    } else if (value instanceof Map) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) value;
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            process(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), newMap);
        }
    } else if (value instanceof List) {
        List<Object> list = (List<Object>) value;
        for (Object obj : list) {
            process(key, obj, newMap);
        }
    }
}
```

You can try any one.

sample code: (using **Jackson Library**)

```
TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeRef = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Map<String, Object> data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    process("menu", data.get("menu"), newMap);
    System.out.println(new JSONObject(newMap));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("There might be some issue with the JSON string");
}
```

---

sample code: using [**GSON Library**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
process("menu", data.get("menu"), newMap);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(newMap));
```

output:

```
{
  "op1": "New",
  "id": "12",
  "op21": "OpenDoc()",
  "op2": "Open",
  "op3": "Close",
  "op11": "CreateNewDoc()",
  "value": "File",
  "op31": "CloseDoc()"
}
```